# I have to capitalize the first letter of a String in Java.(I cant use the method in string class to do so). but i keep getting out of bounds error

Tags: java, arrays

here is the code. I keep getting the error: String index out of range:5, I don't know what I'm doing wrong so any help will be appreciated. Also, I'm not allowed to use any Scanner class methods other than length.

```
   import java.util.*;
   public class capitalLetter
   {
       public static void main(){
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter a non capitalized word");
           String word = sc.next();
           int length = word.length();
           char ch[] = new char[length];
           for(int i = 0;i<length-1;i++){
               ch[length] = word.charAt(length);
           }
           ch[0]+=32;
           for(int i = 0;i<length-1;i++){
               System.out.print(ch[length]);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: *"I don't know what I'm doing wrong so any help will be appreciated."* - Here is my help.  I recommend you read this: [How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  (Reason: you need to learn to debug code for yourself rather than asking for help.)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, within the `for` loop you need to use the loop variable `i`, rather than `length`. Also, `i` should go to the last element of the array.

This

```
for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++){
    ch[length] = word.charAt(length);
}
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    ch[i] = word.charAt(i);
}
```

Secondly, you're adding 32 when you should be subtracting.

Putting this together you get:

```
String word = "hello";
int length = word.length();
char ch[] = new char[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    ch[i] = word.charAt(i);
}
ch[0] -= 32;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.print(ch[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

In both of your loops, you are indexing by `length` instead of by `i`.

e.g this line

```java
               ch[length] = word.charAt(length);
```

should be like this

```java
               ch[i] = word.charAt(i);
```

Comment: thank you! would've never figured this out myself as I'm still learning